# How to preserve entry order when converting pdf to text in python?

Tags: python, pdf, text, pypdf

I am trying to read the text from a pdf file. This file is part of a generated report. I am amble to read the text in the file but it comes out very garbled. What I want is to get each line in the pdf file as an item in a list, eventually, but you can see that the field names and entries get all mixed up. An example of the pdf I am trying to important can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EC2BR7x2NMVRz_wkCv7EGkPD9pqFYL-t), and below is the code that I am trying to use to get the lines.

```
import PyPDF2

try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

filename = 'U:/PLAN/BCUBRICH/Python/Network Plan/Page 1 from AMP380_1741500.pdf'



def getPDFContent(filename):
    content = ""

    p = open(filename, "rb")
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(p)
    pdf.
    num_pages = pdf.getNumPages()
    for i in range(0, num_pages):
        content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText()+'\n'
#    content = " ".join(content.replace(u"\xa0", " ").strip().split())
    return content

content=getPDFContent(filename)
```

**Here is the output I get:**

```
Out:'''UNITED STATES ENVIRONMENTAL PROTECTION AGENCYAIR QUALITY SYSTEMSITE DESCRIPTION REPORTApr. 25, 2019Site ID: 49-003-0003 
Site Name: Brigham City 
Local ID: BR 
140 W.FISHBURN DRIVE, BRIGHAM CITY, UTStreet Address: City: Brigham City 
Utah Zip Code: 84302
State: Box ElderCounty: Monitoring PointLocation Description: SuburbanLocation Setting: Interpolation-MapColl. Method:ResidentialLand Use: 20000819Date Established: Date Terminated: 20190130Last Updated: HQ Eval. Date:Regional Eval. Date: UtahAQCR : Ogden-Clearfield, UTCBSA: Salt Lake City-Provo-Orem, UTCSA: Met. Site ID:Direct Met Site: On-Site Met EquipType Met Site: Dist to Met. Site(m): Local Region: Urban Area: Not in an urban area 
EPA Region: Denver 
17411City Population: Dir. to CBD: Dist. to City(km): 3000Census Block: 3Block Group: 960701Census Tract: 1Congressional District: Class 1 Area: +41.492707Site Latitude: -112.018863Site Longitude: MountainTime Zone: UTM Zone: UTM Northing: UTM Easting: Accuracy: 60.73 
Datum: WGS84 
Scale: 24000 
Point/Line/Area: Point 1,334.0Vertical Measure(m): 0Vert Accuracy: UnknownVert Datum : Vert Method: Unknown 
Owning Agency: 1113 Utah Department Of Environmental Quality SITE COMMENTS SITE FOR OZONE, PM2.5, AND MET ACTIVE MONITOR TYPES Primary Monitor Periods # of Parameter Code Poc Begin Date End Date Monitor Type Monitors 42602 1 20180126 OTHER 2 44201 1 20010501 SLAMS 16 88101 1 20000819 20141231 88101 1 20160101 20161231 88101 1 20180101 88101 3 20170101 20171231 88101 4 20150101 20151231 TANGENT ROADS Road Traffic Traffic Compass Number Road Name Count Year Traffic Volume Source Road Type Sector 1 FISHBURN DRIVE 450 2000 LOCAL ST OR HY S Page 1 of 77
'''
```

For Example, I would like the eighth item in the list to be

```
State: Utah Zip Code: 84302 County: Box Elder
```

but what I get is

```
Utah Zip Code: 84302 State: Box ElderCounty:
```

These kind of mix ups happen throughout the document.

Answer (score 2):

*This is merely an explanation why that happens, not a solution. But it is too long for a comment, so it got an answer...*

**The reason for this weird order is that the text chunks in the document drawn in that order.**

If you dig into the PDF and look at the content stream, you find this segment responsible for the example line you picked:

```
/TD <</MCID 12 >>BDC 
-47.25 -1.685 Td
(Utah )Tj
28.125 0 Td
[(Zip Code: )-190(84302)]TJ
-32.06 -0 Td
(State: )Tj
EMC 
/TD <</MCID 13 >>BDC 
56.81 0 Td
(Box Elder)Tj
-5.625 0 Td
(County: )Tj
EMC
```

You probably don't understand the instructions but can see that the strings (in round brackets `(`...`)`) come exactly in the order you observe in the output

> Utah Zip Code: 84302 State: Box ElderCounty:

instead of the desired

> State: Utah Zip Code: 84302 County: Box Elder

The **Td** instructions in-between make the text insertion point jump back and forth to achieve the different appearance in a viewer.

Apparently your text extraction method merely retrieves the strings from the content stream in the order they are drawn and ignores the actual locations at which they are drawn. For a proper text extraction, therefore, you have to change the method you use. As I don't really know PyPDF2 myself, I cannot say whether this library offers different text extraction methods to turn to or whether you have to resort to a different library.